# Time-series numpy representation: different data, same visualization

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to show a series of matrices of float64 with similar values changing along the time. I have a numpy **frames** which I iterate and show with matplotlib as follows:

```
for frame in frames:
    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.title('Frame %d' % cnt)
    plt.pause(.25)
    plt.draw()
    print(frame[0])
```

Having as a result the same visualization of different frames (bellow the frame, the first row is printed):

[image]

[image]

[image]

They look identical, but the matrix is different. How could I visualize the evolution in time of these frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colormap is normalized for each frame. If you want to see differences between frames, then you should have the same colormap for all the frames.

A simple way would be to use [the `vmin=` and `vmax=` arguments of `imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). Pass the global minimum of all your frames to `vmin=` and the global maximum to `vmax=`

Comment: Why do we need the absolute values?

Comment: I mean the global minimum and maximum, for the whole dataset, not for a single frame